# Is this correct grammar — "which feature in C/C++ don't you like?"

Tags: verbs, word-order, questions, negation

The question in question is this:

> Which feature in C/C++ don't you like?

Just wanted to know if that is proper way of asking. Not sure if "don't you like" is the right way there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct grammar.  *Don't* is informal, so not suitable for, e.g., a manufacturer's survey;  it's unusual to say 'feature' (either 'features' or 'single feature' to emphasize what you want); and a pedant might point out that you don't actually like all the features you've never thought about, so *dislike* would be better.  But these are points of style, and much depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to ask for the reader to respond with a *single* feature of C++ he or she dislikes, I would phrase it:

> Which feature *of* C/C++ don't you like? And how can it be made
>   better?

It's more common to use which *of* or what *of* rather *in*.

As for *which* vs *what*, the Chicago Manual of Style says:

> To refer to a person, animal, or thing, either *which* or *what* may
>   be used {Which one of you did this?} {What kind of bird is that?}.

But I believe *which* is correct in this case because CMS also says:

> *Which* is usually selective or limited; it asks for a particular member of a group, and the answer is limited to the group addressed or
>   referred to.

As TimLymington notes, your question is phrased in an informal way. If that's your intent, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Perhaps a slight restructuring might make the sentence more readable: *Which features of C/C++ do you dislike?*